# Asp.Net WebApi Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have problem with routing generic controller method. I have controller class like this.

```
public abstract class ModelsController<T> : ApiController where T : IModel
{
    [GET("GetByName/{name:string}")]
    public T GetByName(string name)
    {
        return repository.GetByName(name);
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("Events")]
public class EventsController : ModelsController<IEventModel> { }
```

I want have api method on url

```
GET ~/api/public/Photos/GetByName/{name}
```

but url is

```
GET ~/api/public/Photos?name={name}
```

What I have wrong? Whats is the right way to do routing like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[Route]` Attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetByName/{name:string}")]
public T GetByName(string name)
{
    return repository.GetByName(name);
}
```

Is Attribute based routing enabled in the WebApiConfig?

According to Web [API 2.2 documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22) you need the following configuration:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());
public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList 
    GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes
        (inherit: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work for generic controllers, I tried it before I ask.

Comment: Are you using WebApi 2.2?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. I Use Web api 2.2 and MVC 5.2

Comment: did you add the necessary configuration (see my edited post)?